# Unit testing properties of a class using C# and reflection

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I'm facing some difficulties with unit testing in C#.

Let's say I have

```
class Dummy{
    TypeA Foo {get; set;}
    TypeB Bar {get; set;}
}
```

and the test method

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestStuff()
{
    Type type = typeof(Dummy);
    PropertyInfo[] properties = type.GetProperties();

    foreach(PropertyInfo property in properties)
    {
        string result= MyStaticClass.ProcessProperty(property.Name);
        Assert.IsFalse(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(result));
    }
}
```

The test runs fine, but when it fails I have no clue about which property causes the problem.

In other test methods I've used the `[DataTestMethod]` and `[DataRow(stuff)]` in order to provide single inputs and know what caused the test to fail.

Is there a way to do something like this using reflection?

Am I thinking of a wrong unit test?

I'd like to use this approach to check consistency, is it wrong at all?

Comment: Can you not just add a message to your assert  saying what property has failed, etc.?

Comment: Oh... so silly of me... It was what I needed, thanks!

Comment: Interesting test :)

Comment: @Chris probably post that as answer?

Comment: @Rahul: At time of commenting I thought it was too obvious to post as an answer so wanted to confirm whether the OP had just failed to noticed this overload or whether there was a good reason not to want to do that. Now somebody else has saved me the effort of posting an answer. :)

Comment: What's the purpose of this test?

Comment: Basically I'm matching properties to categories using their names. I'm doing some refactoring and wanted to make sure that every property still had a category.
By the way, @Chris post your answer, I'll accept it since you got here first :)

Comment: And yeah, I didn't notice this overload haha!

Comment: @magicleon: I've not really got anything to add that isn't in Carlos's answer so not going to post my own. I'm happy for him to get the upvotes and the accept. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Assert](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.assert?view=mstest-net-1.2.0) has many interesting properties params!

You can do something like:

```
Assert.IsFalse(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(result), $"{property.Name} is null");
```